# Propagate up/down swipe event from ViewPager2 to parent BottomSheet

Tags: android, swipe, bottom-sheet, android-viewpager2

I'm having a `BottomSheetBehavior` view which contains a `ViewPager2`. Both work well and do what they need except trying to swipe the `BottomSheet` up/down on the `ViewPager2`.
Again, swipe up/down on `BottomSheet` works well if the finger is above or below the `ViewPager2`, except when the finger is ON the `ViewPager2`.

I need to find out how to propagate the up/down swipe events through the `ViewPager2` down to the `BottomSheet`.

The code is very fragmented, so it'll be complicated to show it here and wouldn't really make sense. I just need the principle of how to propagate the events.

Comment: I once did overriding onInterceptTouchEvent and onTouchEvent in both parent view plus the child views that has the behaviour but dont have access to this code anymore, but worked smoothly, nowdays I remember seeing some new classes but didnt tried with those maybe scrolling behaviour and other things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to that the nested scrolling of the inner `RecyclerView` of the ViewPager2 is enabled by default. To disable it:

```
viewPager.children.find { it is RecyclerView }?.let {
        (it as RecyclerView).isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
}
```